# Changing Text Input from Chrome Bookmark

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I am trying to fill out text input's on a site that does not have JQuery. However, I keep getting a null return when trying to use Javascript's getElementById function with a Google Chrome Bookmark.

**How to replicate:**

Go to W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_value2

Add this as a bookmark:

```
javascript:(function(){
    console.log(document.getElementById("myText"));
})();
```

Click on the bookmark and see "null" in the console instead of the text input.

(To get the desired output you can change W3's code to console.log the element instead of changing it's value and then click the W3's "Try it" button)

--

The goal here is to be able to change these text input values by script.

Ex) Change "Mickey" to "Johnny Bravo" through bookmark click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag the padlock icon to your bookmarks toolbar, right-click, edit and set the URL to:

```
javascript:document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";document.close();
```

Then click it to change the value of myText. You need to close the document after setting the value or it will write to a new document.

The bookmarklet above won't work in your TryIt editor because the form is in an iFrame named 'iframeResult'. But this works:

```
javascript: window.frames.iframeResult.document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";document.close();
```

Comment: You are AMAZING! Thank you so much! One thing I didn't realize is the page I was trying to manipulate and the w3schools page were both in iframe. It was your window.frames that saved the day! I had to use window.frames.[fameID].contentDocument in order to get things to work but because of you I was able to arrive to that result and the bookmarklet is working perfect! Thank you again!